# ACTION_GET_CONTENT except image and video files in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

If we have to get the image file from device then we have to write following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setType("image/*");  
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Picture"), 1);
```

But what we have to do if we don't want to choose only image and video files.

I want that the file chooser window should show all the files except image and video.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no option for this.